# Avoid multiple if's inside for loop

Tags: python

I have a function which creates data

```
from faker import Faker
import pandas as pd
import random

def create_rows_faker(num=1, name_col = True, address_col = True, email_col = False):
    output = []
    for x in range(num):
        out = {}
        if name_col:
            out["name"] = fake.name()
        if address_col:
            out["address"] = fake.address()
        if email_col:
            out["email"] = fake.email()
        output.append(out)
    return output
```

but I want to remove the multiple if statements inside the for loop. What is the best method to improve this?

Comment: Whats wrong with them?

Comment: the response is known for each iteration

Comment: I'm not sure what that means

Comment: is there a way to take the ifs outside of the for loop for sake of speed and beauty?

Comment: No, there isn't

Comment: @Sayse That's not wholly true, though I don't think you'll get much speed out of it. Premature optimization is the root of all evil and all that.

Comment: @NathanielFord - In my opinion it is, for example your answer doubles the number of iterations the op is doing, the op's approach still appears to be the preferred way to do this to me

Comment: @Sayse Doubles? I think you should check your math there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking the columns as separate arguments, use a list of column names. You can then loop over this list, and fill in `out` with the corresponding fakes, using `getattr()` to call the methods dynamically.

```
from copy import deepcopy

def create_rows_faker(num=1, columns):
    output = []
    for _ in range(num):
        out = {col: getattr(fake, col)() for col in columns}
        output.append(out)
    return output
```

Comment: It is repeating the same fake in each row though

Comment: I didn't realize that `fake.XXX()` returns a different result each time.

Comment: ah, did you mean to store output as a list?

Comment: yes, just as in your original code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this really is going to be any faster, because copying dictionaries does take at least as much time as doing if statements, but you can create the dictionary once and then copy it in to your output as needed.

```
def create_mock_rows(num: int = 1, 
                     name_col: bool = True, 
                     address_col: bool = True, 
                     email_col: bool = True) -> list:
    out = {
        "name": fake.name() if name_col else None,
        "address": fake.address() if address_col else None,
        "email": fake.email() if email_col else None,
    }
    return [ {k: v for k, v in out.items() if v is not None} for _ in range(num)]
```

Another option is to leverage `**kwargs`:

```
def create_mock_rows(num: int = 1, **kwargs) -> list:
    return [{k: getattr(fake, v)() for k, v in kwargs.items()} for _ in range(num)]
```

I admit I don't love this, though, because `kwargs` could be anything, and there is some chance of this just failing or giving you a weird result if improperly called.

Comment: Only problem is this generates the same name, address, email each iteration

Comment: @user309575 Ah... well, it was unclear that the `fake.thing()` function returns new items each time. To be honest, what you probably want to write is a generator function that spits out a single dictionary and can be called howmany ever times. But that doesn't solve the question you asked about.

Comment: @user309575 I also added an option that combines `Barmar` and `Tripathi`'s answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use kwargs and dictionary

```
def create_rows_faker(num=1, **kwargs):
    output = []
    es = {"name": fake.name(), "address": fake.address(), "email": fake.email()}
    for x in range(num):
        output.append({key: es[key] for key in kwargs.keys() if kwargs.get(key) })
    return output

create_rows_faker(num=1, name=True, address=True, email=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost every language provides a switch statement:

```
switch(col.key) {
 case "name":
  col.val = fake.name();
  break;
 case "address":
  col.val = fake.address();
  break;
 ...
 default:
  throw new InvalidDataException();
```

As of version 3.10, Python added something similar: P634 - Structural Pattern Matching.

```
match subject:
    case <pattern_1>:
        <action_1>
    case <pattern_2>:
        <action_2>
    case <pattern_3>:
        <action_3>
    case _:
        <action_wildcard>
```